# What is the proper way of converting a timestamp to a human readable date?

Tags: php, date, time

i've got 2 time stamps: `$start_time = 1312346227;` and `$end_time = 1312346466;`
and i am trying to substract them to see the time inbetween `$end_time = $end_time - $start_time;`

and i get `239`.

What is the proper way of converting this to a human readable date?

if i try `echo date("h:i:s A",$end_time);` i get `04:03:59` and it should be `00:03:59`

any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get addiionl four hours, because of your timezone. Remember that unix timestamp is the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC. If you (or your server) are in UTC+4 TZ, then `date()` will implicitly do a timezone conversion to your local time.

Solution? Use [`gmdate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) instead

Comment: I don't think this has to do with the OP's problem - he has a number of seconds (which `date()` formats as seconds from January 1, 1970) and needs to format it as an interval. Timezones don't come into it.

Comment: It is true that `DateInterval` is in general better solution (as long as you don't try it on Windows to caclulate days between two dates). Using `date()/gmdate()` is kind of abusing these functions, but will work as long as you remember about timezone conversion done by `date()`

Comment: it is working, the only thing i had to use `H` so it will use 24h , `gmdate("H:i:s",$end_time)`

Answer (score 4):

If you have PHP 5.3, use the [`DateInterval`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) class.

Example stolen from the manual page on [`DateInterval::format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.format.php):

```
<?php

$january = new DateTime('2010-01-01');
$february = new DateTime('2010-02-01');
$interval = $february->diff($january);

// %a will output the total number of days.
echo $interval->format('%a total days')."\n";

// While %d will only output the number of days not already covered by the
// month.
echo $interval->format('%m month, %d days');

?>
```

Comment: Just be aware, that due to a bug in 5.3 (and I thik in 5.4 too) in Windows `echo $interval->format('%a total days')."\n";` will echo `6015 total days`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your timezone correctly. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php